# Timer is not processing

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I create a windows service to run a piece of code and implemented timer in it to run it periodically.

My timer class is :

```
class TimerClass
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public static void Main()
    {

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }


    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        DatabaseUpdation dbUp = new DatabaseUpdation();
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\New Folder\My Documents\demo\abc.txt", "Start" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        dbUp.GetDatafromSource();

        aTimer.Start();
    }

}
```

And i am calling it from my Start method:

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        TimerClass timer = new TimerClass();
    }
```

But timer is not executing at all.
Can anyone find me the mistake here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why a `static void Main` in your TimerClass ? Where do you call method Main in your code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, read about [Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ace5hbzh.aspx)

your initialization code should not be in public `static void Main()`, but instead in `public TimerClass()`

```
class TimerClass
{
    private System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

    public TimerClass()
    {
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        aTimer.Stop();
        DatabaseUpdation dbUp = new DatabaseUpdation();
        File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\New Folder\My Documents\demo\abc.txt", "Start" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
        dbUp.GetDatafromSource();
        aTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

also your methods and aTimer should not be static.

Comment: is there anything i need to change in OnStart() ?

Comment: Are you sure? 1. You have 5 seconds pause on timer. 2. You will not be notified if this code timer throws an exception.

Comment: Ya i got the thing its running now Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `Main` method to start timer:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    TimerClass.Main();
}
```

BTW not very good name - I think something like `Start` will be better. Also I hope this is not your app entry point method.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to start your timer. Move it outside your elapse. Elapse is only called when your timer is expired.

```
aTimer.Start();
```

FYI you don't need to enable your timer once you call the start method

Comment: No, that's equivalent to `Enabled = true`.

Comment: `timer.Enabled = true` is equivalent to `timer.Start()`

Comment: He's restarting the timer in the "Elapsed" method. Should be perfectly legal.

Comment: @Sebastian Krysmanski, @ Raphaël Althaus that's cool. I'm using timer also and usually I have enable=true and call the start method. So If I enable the timer no need to Start it right?

Comment: @JobertEnamno Correct. Internally, `Timer.Start()` just executes `Enabled = true`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class TimerClass
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        public static void Main()
        {

            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

            aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

            aTimer.Interval = 5000;


            GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);

        }
        public static void Start()
        {
           aTimer.Start();


        }



        private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            aTimer.Stop();
            DatabaseUpdation dbUp = new DatabaseUpdation();
            File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Documents and Settings\New Folder\My Documents\demo\abc.txt", "Start" + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
            dbUp.GetDatafromSource();

            aTimer.Start();
        }

    }
```

---

and you need to call it like this:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //TimerClass timer = new TimerClass();<==No need it's static class!!!
        TimerClass.Main();
        TimerClass.Start();
    }
```